# asyncio and threading: why is the thread id always the same?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, python-asyncio

With the simplest example of a pure TCP asyncio server I could write, I want to get the thread id of the *current thread*. Because I'm in a `async` coroutine, I thought this would be in a different thread (especially with `asyncio` library). But the result always prints the same `id` value. What am I missing? Is it the wrong function call? Does the `asyncio` *not* create a new thread?

```
import asyncio
import threading
from asyncio import StreamWriter, StreamReader

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 7070

async def handle(reader: StreamReader, writer: StreamWriter):
    print(f"{threading.get_native_id()=} / {threading.get_ident()=}")
    writer.close()


async def main():
    server = await asyncio.start_server(handle, HOST, PORT)
    async with server:
        await server.serve_forever()

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: Being single-threaded is pretty much the *point* of asyncio - if you wanted to write concurrent code that uses multiple threads, you can do that without asyncio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) library works in a single OS thread. Basically it's all about the event loop and coroutines being run by that event loop. asyncio applies the concept of cooperative multitasking - a coroutine itself decides when to bring control back to the event loop.

As for multithreading, I suggest you to read [this article about GIL](https://realpython.com/python-gil/). Running multiple threads will not give you any performance gain because of GIL. That's why the key to performance gain (mostly with I/O bound tasks) is to use things like gevent/asyncio. Those libraries will manage "switching between tasks" (i.e. OS scheduler is not applied).